# ArcGIS Desktop Composite Bands Tool is changing my band names

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, sentinel-2, composite

I have a Sentinel 2a raster that I'm trying to do a false colour composite for. The problem is that when I composite the bands, the output seems to have different bands. By deafult, the output has RGB as bands 1,2,3 and this seems to show a true colour image. If I select what I thought should be true colour composite (Band 4, Band 3, Band 2), the image looks whack.

This is a bit confusing because I have no idea which wavelengths that each band in the output raster represent.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the settings you use in Composite bands?